# Embedding jasper server 5 into my existing web application

Tags: jsp, iframe, jasperserver

I need to use JasperReports Server 5.0 commercial into a JSP web application. I need my web app frame (outer frame, menus) and embed JasperReports Server as iFrame in HTML. I can bypass the login of JasperReports Server via Single Sign On. I wonder how can i get JasperReports Server inside the frame. Is there any way I can do it?

Comment: I tried giving "decorate = no" which will removes all default css , but i need a proper customization .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this the easiest way is to develop a theme for JasperReports Server which is basically customized CSS uploaded to JasperReports Server as theme.

- login as *superuser*
- navigate to folder *Themes* in the Repository
- Right click and add new theme
- upload a file `overrides_custom.css` that contains your customizations.

Customizations can be:

- hiding the menu, footer etc
- applying custom color schemes.

Solving it this way allows to have a portable solution between JRS instances without being required to change any file on system level.

More information on themes can be found:

- Chapter 5 - Themes (Admin Guide)
- Chapter 11 - Customizing the User Interface (Ultimate Guide).

Both are available in [Jaspersoft Community](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation) for download.